# No TCP connection on private network with port 443 enabled

Tags: twilio, private-network

I am working on a project where we are streaming video using the Japan Twilio server. The video is showing up when I use 4G or a public network, but not on the private network.

On the public network, the chrome webrtc internals gives me the following info:
iceServers: [turn:tokyo.turn.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp, turns:tokyo.turn.twilio.com:443?transport=tcp].

I am not seeing any video stream when using the private network.
On the private network *.twilio.com is whitelisted, and so is all outgoing traffic on port 443.
The twilio test also shows no connection for UDP, TCP and TLS.

Do you have any recommendations to how I can fix or debug this problem?